# How can I normalize audio track in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, avaudioplayer, just-audio

I am using [Just Audio Player](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio). I want to normalize song while playing.

I tried using setVolume function but its only change the volume of the player. It does not normalize the song.
What I want is a package that support audio normalizeation while playig and It is posible in flutter or not?.

Comment: I don't know if any other audio players support it, but feel free to submit a feature request to just_audio because it already has an architecture to support audio effects, and this could be added if requested.